# Doctrine2 silently fails to insert data

Tags: php, mysql, insert, doctrine-orm

I am using `Doctrine` and it fails to `INSERT` data the first time I do a `persist/flush` but works the second time, and fails the 3rd time:

```
// there is no code executed between any of the attempts

$entity = new My\Entity();
$entity->setTag('A');  // just a random field
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
// INSERT not performed
// if I exit here and check the database, no entry is added

$entity = new My\Entity();
$entity->setTag('B');
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
// INSERT performed
// if I exit here and check the database, 1 entry has been added
// and I can see it's "B"

$entity = new My\Entity();
$entity->setTag('C');
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
// INSERT not performed
// if I exit here and check the database, there is still only 1 entry added
// and I can see it's "B"
```

Here is what I notice on failing attempts:
- There is nothing in the `PHP logs` (`error_reporting` is set to all, other Doctrine and PHP issues, including warnings, do show up in the logs).
- The `Doctrine SQLLogger` doesn't show anything (on the second attempt it does show the `INSERT`).

Some troubleshooting steps:
- I wanted to troubleshoot further by replacing the failing attempt with a `DQL` `INSERT` query but ["INSERT statements are not allowed in DQL"](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) :(
- Doing an additional `flush` before instantiating `$entity` in the failing attempt doesn't help
- I can insert as many entries as I want to the database manually and it works, even on first attempt.
- I have the same issue with `2.4.0-DEV`.
- I have the same issue with `2.2.2`.

I might add that the code is executed inside a `PHPunit` test, and that in a previous test, I am not experiencing the issue (i.e. Doctrine does properly perform an `INSERT` on the first `persist/flush`).

**Any idea where the problem might be coming from ?**

Version info:
-`PHP 5.4`
-`Doctrine 2.3.0` (`pdo_mysql` driver)
-`MySQL 5.5.24`
-`Ubuntu 12.04`
-`PHPUnit 3.7.7`

### Update 1:

Alright, this is part of the answer. The problem seems to by a routine I use in my `PHPUnit` `setUp()` to truncate my database tables between each test:

- if I truncate my tables between each test, I have problems (i.e. some `INSERT`s fail).
- if I don't truncate, everything works fines.

The way the `INSERT`s fail seem to be mode random than initially thought, as I created 2 tests of 3 inserts each (and only ran those). When truncating tables between each test, here is what happens to the 3 inserts in each test:
-test 1: SUCCESS / SUCCESS / SUCCESS
-test 2: SUCCESS / SUCCESS / FAILURE (I don't have FAILURE / SUCCESS / FAILURE like I used to).

Here is the piece of code I'm using to truncate the tables:

```
$cmd = $em->getClassMetadata($className);
$connection = $em->getConnection();
$dbPlatform = $connection->getDatabasePlatform();
$connection->beginTransaction();
try {
    $connection->query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');
    $q = $dbPlatform->getTruncateTableSql($cmd->getTableName());
    $connection->executeUpdate($q);
    $connection->query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');
    $connection->commit();
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
    $connection->rollback();
}
```

I got the code from [this SO post](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) and as far as I can see it looks good. I have the same issue if I use [this other code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526534/how-to-truncate-a-table-using-doctrine-in-symfony):

```
$connection = $entityManager->getConnection();
$platform   = $connection->getDatabasePlatform();
$connection->executeUpdate($platform->getTruncateTableSQL('my_table', true /* whether to cascade */));
```

I modified my schema to test with and without the foreign keys and I have the same issue in both cases.

Comment: How do you know it isn't working the first time and failing the second time?

Comment: Because if I exit after the first attempt and check the database, there is no entry inserted. I'll add that to the code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it appears that the issue occurred when:
-truncating the tables between each test in the `setUp` function.
`AND`
-instantiating the Doctrine instance only once in `setUpBeforeClass` (that I was then accessing with `self::$em`).

If I don't truncate the tables between each test `OR` if I instantiate my Doctrine instance in `setUp`, everything works fine.

I used to like `setUpBeforeClass`, not such more anymore...